# Сохранит куки curl php

Tags: php, curl

Почему такой код не сохраняет куки?

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ocservice.taobao.com/cookieController/processUserCookie?site=CN_zh-CN_CNY_156&callback=jsonp_1546706091271_92560');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt');
$http_headers = array(
                'Host: www.google.ca',
                'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2',
                'Accept: */*',
                'Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5',
                'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
                'Connection: keep-alive'
              );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забыл обработать https, поэтому данный скрипт не работает в принципе от слова вообще:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

[Документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php) смотрите внимательнее.

Answer (score -1):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__ . "/cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ . "/cookies.txt");
```